# how to list all the teams in the Office 365 tenant

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I would like to have the list of all the teams that are created in the Office 365 tenant.

Pls share if there are any working examples in powershell or by any other means.

Answer (score 0):

Using Graph API you can get list of all the teams using [joinedTeams API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams).

For samples, please follow [Graph API samples](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks).

If you want to test the Graph API you can try the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

Comment: will it list all the teams even if i dont have access, I am a SharePoint Admin for the tenant but wanted to know the teams and its internal sites. pls confirm.

Comment: as per developers documentation and graph api, it will only list the the teams that you are part of.. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams